# Which sentence is correct in the punctuation system?

Tags: punctuation

In the following sentences, which sentence is correct in the punctuation system?

> 1. As the game proceeds we hear the umpire calling out: zero-1; 1-1; 3-2; or 6-8 as the case may be.
> 2. As the game proceeds we hear the umpire calling out zero-1, 1-1, 3-2, or 6-8 as the case may be.

Comment: Please give us the context

Answer (score -1):

Use commas for a list unless one (or more) of the items contains an internal comma, in which case you use semicolons for the list:

- Apple, Google and Facebook
- Apple, Inc.; Google, Inc. and Facebook, Inc.

None of your list items contain a comma, so the list itself can use commas.

Comment: Downvoter: please provide feedback so I know what to improve.